# How to structure database calls in a page?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, web-applications

Ok so i am new to making complex database structure into the page. I have a basic people table with a few categories. Students, teachers, parents and mods. There are again tables one for parents, students and teachers/mods. Its basically a school's website.

Now for example for a profile page where a student's info is showed to parents. Info like who are teachers, subjects, attendance, homework, etc. This will query a lot of tables. So what is my best bet here? I plan to do it in a web-app way. I was thinking maybe i can JSON data to page with ajax and let javascript do the heavy lifting of calculation. All the tables will only be queried once.

So is it even ok to do so? or will i face some hidden problems when i have dug my feet too deep in it? Maybe i can go one more level deep and make a huge JSON with entire database being sent to user and then it is cached in the browser. I dont have to support really old browsers :)

Also things like attendance and marks/result will need to be calculated every time. Is there any way to cache the result per student? like wen a parent views a student's result, it calculates it once and then caches it for x number of days on the server somehow.

**EDIT:**

Another non JSON approach i can think of is traditional way. I do all the things on server side with php. This means i wont have to worry about browser compatibility. Maybe i can make a call to all the needed tables in the beginning and store it is an array. That way a table only gets called once too.

**EDIT 2**

I read somewhere about battlefield 3 battlelog website. It is also made the same way. All the data is pulled from server with JSON and then calculated on client side. If that helps put my idea in perspective.

Comment: There are always hidden problems. There are always multiple ways you can do this. Start with something to learn. I suggest you either start with plain PHP and mysql or if you really wanna fancy out JSON so much, do it with couchdb and javascript only.

Comment: @hakre I was thinking about JASON because javascript is some thing i am very comfortable with. But unfortunately i don't think i can work with anything other than mysql because that is only database i know and this is production code.

Comment: "Jason" is the guy from all those "Friday the 13th" movies :).  You're thinking of "JavaScript Object Notation", or "JSON".

Comment: @paulsm4 agrrh its kind of morning here and i have been working all night. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably to move away some misconceptions, but this is more a lengthy comment than an answer:

Your database has tables and fiels. That's perfectly valid. It's the job of a database server to store the data and handle the querying for you. Your own code will never be better in joining tables than the code of the database. Because the database server is optimized for the task.

So I think the idea to query all data and put it into your webapp via JSON is just a bad idea. Instead contact your server if you need specific data, the server will build the related SQL query, fire it up to the database server, get's the result back, converts the result into JSON and sends it back to the browser.

Comment: Thanks! But what about things like calculating results? This usually needs a lot of calculation specially when viewing class average since marks are added per question. So instead of querying the database to first get result per exam, then per student and then make it per class would be better done by getting the required questions and student data out and then using JavaScript to do the multilevel calculations and joining marks to students because JS would generaly be faster and more efficient at it because every user will take it's own load instead of single server doing it for all of them.

Comment: MySQL has aggregation functions as well and can do arithmetical calculations as well. I wonder if that's not fast as well as this can reduce the amount of data that you need to transfer between your server and browser. Server side calculations are probably even faster than transferring the whole data over the wire. But probably not. Then you need to find out which of the two alternatives are faster if you're concerned about speed and try it out. You never know in advance.

Comment: Hmm seieng that doing it javascript way would still require the browser compatibility thingy, i think i should do it server side. What do you think about making the call to every table needed in beginning of the page and store it in a variable and i can then use it multiple times throughout the page without making calls to a table again. What are the conventional ways to deal with situations where info from one table is needed but depends of data from another? Making db calls in a loop is wrong.. right?

Comment: The standard way is to query the database with a JOIN statement. You can ask for data across multiple tables with one query. I think that's the main part you're looking for. Here is a tutorial: http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php

Comment: _exactly!_ I think that is what i needed. Thanks a ton! And sorry it appears it was difficult for me to describe my situation :P

Answer (score 0):

AJAX (Asynchronus Javascript and XML) just allows you to fetch data on the fly after the main portion of the page is painted.  All things being equal it might be easier for you to design it as a standard (fetch data then paint the page) layout.  If you design the application correctly the calls to do the individual components (Attendance, Teachers, Grades, etc.) can be gathered pre-page-render or post page render.   There's obvious security concerns (URL hacking) by going the AJAX route, and I personally design non-AJAX as it's less flukey when things start going wierd.

Comment: I agree with what you say but in this case the server is very average with low bandwidths. (low budget) So i have to use the resources judiciously so that it does not pull the site down on the day result gets out.

As for non ajax approach, what do you think about making the call to every table needed in beginning of the page and store it in a variable and i can then use it multiple times throughout the page.

Comment: @Achshar You might be able to get away with a SQL view to do some pre-processing, and the server layer to do more.  If you're really worried about throughput I'd first profile my code to ensure I'm not executing a lot of unnecessary loops and also look for the largest nails to hit down first.  It really depends on the amount of data you're needing to query up versus the amount of visitors you're expecting to have versus the computing level that your visitors will have.  It does nothing for them by unloading the data calculations on a PoS computer that should have been retired over 10 years ago

Comment: indeed. I will JOIN the statements and query them once still staying at the server side with php. That seems to be the answer. Thanks!